# Want horizontal scrolling to stick with columns instead of whole pages (fragments)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I want to show several columns in one Activity. If there are more columns than can actually fit the screen, user should be able to swipe left and right to move among these columns. This can by easily done by `ViewPager` or `HorizontalScrollView`.

However I would like the user to see each adjacent columns on one screen.

A picture should better explain my intention:
[image: Sticky scrolling]

(to clip or to stick.. don't know what word I should use)

Am I able to make `ViewPager` or `HorizontalScrollView` to stick with columns instead of whole pages (fragments)?

Or do you please know of any open source projects that achieve desired behaviour of `ViewPager` / `HorizontalScrollView`?

**EDIT:** I've found out that similar behaviour appears in a few examples of API Demos app!

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is probably snap!? As in, snap the columns to the activity edges when swiping.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, do you have any idea how to achieve such behaviour?